# How can I serve HTTP slowly?

Tags: http, load-testing

I'm working on an http client and I would like to test it on requests that take some time to finish.  I could certainly come up with a python script to suit my needs, something about like:

```
def slow_server(environ, start_response):
    with getSomeFile(environ) as file_to_serve:
        block = file_to_serve.read(1024);
        while block:
            yield block
            time.sleep(1.0)
            block = file_to_serve.read(1024);
```

but this feels like a problem others have already encountered.  Is there an easy way to serve static files with an absurdly low bandwidth cap, short of a full scale server like apache or nginx.

I'm working on linux, and the way I've been testing so far is with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` in a directory full of files to serve.  I'm equally interested in another simple command line server or a way to do bandwidth limiting with one or a few iptables commands on tcp port 8000 (or whatever would work).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution I'm going with for now uses a "real" webserver, but a much easier to configure one, lighttpd.  I've added the following file to my path (its in `~/bin`)

```
#! /usr/sbin/lighttpd -Df

server.document-root = "/dev/null"
server.modules = ("mod_proxy")
server.kbytes-per-second = env.LIGHTTPD_THROTTLE
server.port = env.LIGHTTPD_PORT
proxy.server  = ( "" => (( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => env.LIGHTTPD_PROXY )))
```

Which is a lighttpd config file that acts as a reverse proxy to localhost; source and destination ports, as well as a server total maximum bandwidth are given as environment variables, and so it can be invoked like:

```
$ cd /path/to/some/files
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 &
$ LIGHTTPD_THROTTLE=60 LIGHTTPD_PORT=8001 LIGHTTPD_PROXY=8000 throttle.lighttpd
```

to proxy the python file server on port 8000 with a low 60KB per second on port 8001. Obviously, lighttpd could be used to serve the files itself, but this little script can be used to make *any* http server slow

Comment: Great solution, I created a small Docker container based on that: https://hub.docker.com/r/pbertera/lighttpd-throttle/

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use Fiddler which is a HTTP proxy debugging tool to simulate very slow speeds.  Maybe a similar tool exists on what ever OS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I once had the same question and my search turned up an Apache2 module that goes by the name of **[mod_bw](http://bwmod.sourceforge.ne)** (mod_bandwith that is). It served me well for my testings.

Comment: It's something I can do with nginx easily enough. what I'm really looking for though, is a zero setup solution about as easy as `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in a directory full of files.